# How to delay one transition but not the other?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have two transitions set for `#circle`.

**I want only the opacity to have a delay, but I can only make it where both of the transitions do.**

My full goal is to make the opacity change when the circle is mid spin (so at exactly 90deg).

But I will work out the timing myself, **I just want to know how to give the delay to only one transition**.

```
#circle {
  background-color:black;
  background-image:url('rain.img');
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
  border-radius:100%;
  margin:0 auto;
  perspective:1000;
  transition:transform 2s, opacity .1s;
}

#circle:hover {
  perspective:1000px;
  transform:rotateY(180deg);
  opacity:.25;
}
```

I imagine you will only need to see the CSS, but if you think you need to see the **full code go here** ===> https://jsfiddle.net/z49kd9qk/

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Solution

The `transition-delay` function can only be parsed as the second timing value.

Instead of this:

```
transition: transform 2s, opacity .1s;
```

Work with this:

```
transition: transform 2s 0s, opacity 0s 2s;
```

---

### Explanation

When working with the `transition` shorthand property, the order and presence of components matter. Here's the basic order and composition:

```
<transition-property> <transition-duration> <transition-timing-function> <transition-delay>
```

If the `transition-property` component is left out, the shorthand property applies `all`.

If the `transition-timing-function` component is left out, the shorthand applies `ease`.

(Both are the initial values of the respective properties.)

So you can minimize the declaration to this:

```
<transition-duration> <transition-delay>
```

If only one value is declared (like in your code), it will always be applied to `transition-duration`.

So with this:

```
transition: transform 2s, opacity .1s;
```

... you're applying a timing duration to both properties.

The `transition-delay` function can only be parsed as the second timing value.

*Per your question:*

> I want only the opacity to have a delay but I can only make it where both of the transitions do.

Then do this instead:

```
transition: transform 2s 0s, opacity 0s 2s;
```

[revised fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z49kd9qk/1/)

```css
#circle {
  background-color: black;
  background-image: url('https://media.giphy.com/media/eNMHeFodYv8Os/giphy.gif');
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  perspective: 1000;
  /* transition:transform 2s, opacity .1s; */
  transition: transform 2s 0s, opacity 0s 2s;
}
#circle:hover {
  perspective: 1000px;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  opacity: .25;
}
#cloud {
  height: 70px;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  left: 10%;
  top: 105px;
}
#temp {
  font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
  position: relative;
  left: 45%;
  font-size: 100px;
  bottom: 100px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id='circle'>
  <img src='http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/rain-cloud-icon-5.png' id='cloud'>
  <h2 id='temp'>54°</h2>
</div>
```